# Array methods inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a very simple html document with some vanilla JavaScript to sort some elements in it.

I've been able to use `.map()` to print all the elements of an array, but I'd like to include them in html elements. For example. using an `<h1>` or a `<p>`.

This is the code I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body onload="mapping()">
  <h1>
    <script>
      const array = [1, 2, 3];

      function mapping() {
        array.map(arrayItem => {
          document.write(arrayItem)
        })
      }

    </script>
  </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I include HTML inside the script, so I can do something with each one of those returned elements? I mean, something like this:

```
<script>
  const array = [1, 2, 3];
  function mapping() {
    array.map(arrayItem => {
      <h1>document.write(arrayItem)</h1>
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain what you are going to achieve?

Comment: Trying to use those elements with HTML, putting them inside an h1 or a p, for example, like you can see on the second snippet, so I can do something for each one of those elements returned from the map.

Comment: You shouyld use `document.createElement("[name of element]")` to make elements based off of items in the array, than use `appendChild([newlyCreatedElement])` to add it to the document

I can't help much more than that without clearer instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body onload="mapping()">
  <script>
      const array = [1, 2, 3];
      function mapping() {
        array.forEach(arrayItem => {
          var newEle = document.createElement('h1');
          newEle.innerHTML = arrayItem;
          document.body.appendChild(newEle);
        });
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work. In case of wanting to add some styling, how do I add classes to those h1?

Comment: Stick in `newEle.classList.add("myclass");`

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```html
<div> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.write("<h1>Main title</h1>") 
  </script> 
 </div>
```

You might want to consider checking the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/write) for Javascript at the link I provided. It gives a lot of useful examples and methods. 
I took the  snippet code from there.
Hope it helps.